# Find the least positive integer such that $x^2 \equiv 20 \pmod{19}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the least positive integer $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv 20 \pmod{19}$

After finding the perfect square which is $324=18^2$, so the answers are:$$x \equiv 1 \pmod{19}$$ and $$x\equiv 18 \pmod{19}$$ So any numbers of the form $19n+1$ and $19n+18$ satisfies the equation, my question is the least positive integer should be $1$ and $18$ or only $1$?. Thanks for your help!

Comment: 'my question is the least positive integer should be 1 and 18 or only 1?' how can there be two distinct least positive integers?

Comment: I thought they are different because they are in $2$ different form, so the least integer of the form $19n+1$ is $1$ and the least integer of the form $19n+18$ is $18$.

Comment: The least positive integer implies the smallest positive integer, of which there should only be 1. Doesn't matter the form it comes in. 1 should be your solution here

Comment: You seek the least positive integer in the positive solution set $\,[\pm1]_{19} = \{1, 18, 20, 37,\ldots\}$. That is $1$. What you describe is the least positive representative of each congruence class of the two solutions $\,[1]_{19} = \{\ldots,-18,1,20,\ldots\},$ and $\,[-1]_{19} = \{\ldots,-1,18,37,\ldots\},\,$ which is $1$ and $18$. But that's not what was asked.